# how can i use fb_server_fbml helper method in facebooker2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebooker2

I am developing a facebook app using rails 3 and facebooker2 
i cannot find any example on how to use fb_server_fbml helper method.
what is "proc" in its paramter. Can anyone provide me with sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `&proc` parameter is used as a content block that is inserted between the `<fb:serverFbml>` tags. You can learn more about block helpers and differences between Rails 2.3 and Rails 3 here: [Block Helpers in Rails 3](http://timelessrepo.com/block-helpers-in-rails3)

So, try something like this:

```
<% fb_server_fbml do %>
  <%#Insert here your content %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to use the request form, try the following:

```
<% fb_server_fbml do %>
  <% fb_request_form("Your app name","http://www.example.com/callback","Try this out!") do %>
    <%= fb_multi_friend_selector("Invite your friends:", {:rows => 3}) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks gparis
it did work but not as it should 

instead of rendering the html it dumped it on the page any idea why is this happening
I have other helper function working like fb_profile_pic.

fb_connect_async_js also does the same i.e it dumps all the html on page instead of rending it.

I fixed the fb_connect_async_js problem by copying the html dumped on page into my code. Is this something to do with html safe string?